# New Oracle Package with Stored Procedure Including Parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, package

I am having difficulty with writing my stored procedure within a package.  Below is my stored procedure that compiles fine outside of the package,  but I believe needs to be written differently within the package body.  I admit this is my first time using a package...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_COMMENT(P_MEMBER_ID IN VARCHAR2, P_MEMBER_LASTNAME IN 
VARCHAR2, P_MEMBER_FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2, P_MEMBER_STARTDATE IN DATE,
P_MEMBER_ENDDATE IN DATE, P_PRODUCT_CAT_CODE IN VARCHAR2, P_COMMENT IN VARCHAR2,    
COMMENT_CURSOR out sys_refcursor) 

AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'INSERT INTO TEST
 (
MEMBER_ID,
MEMBER_LASTNAME,
MEMBER_FIRSTNAME,
MEMBER_STARTDATE,
MEMBER_ENDDATE,
PRODUCT_CAT_CODE,
COMMENTS
 )
 VALUES
 (
p_member_id,
p_member_lastname,
p_member_firstname,
p_member_startdate,
p_member_enddate,
p_product_cat_code,
p_comment)';

commit;   
open COMMENT_CURSOR for select * from sconti.TEST;
END;
```

Below is the package that I started, and which is not working:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE 
 PACKAGE COMMENT_TEST IS 

  PROCEDURE SP_COMMENT(P_MEMBER_ID IN VARCHAR2, P_MEMBER_LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
  P_MEMBER_FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2, P_MEMBER_STARTDATE IN DATE, 
  P_MEMBER_ENDDATE IN DATE, P_PRODUCT_CAT_CODE IN VARCHAR2, P_COMMENT IN VARCHAR2,  
  COMMENT_CURSOR out sys_refcursor) IS
  BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'INSERT INTO TEST
  (
  MEMBER_ID,
  MEMBER_LASTNAME,
MEMBER_FIRSTNAME,
MEMBER_STARTDATE,
MEMBER_ENDDATE,
PRODUCT_CAT_CODE,
COMMENTS
  )
   VALUES
   (
   p_member_id,
   p_member_lastname,
   p_member_firstname,
p_member_startdate,
p_member_enddate,
p_product_cat_code,
p_comment)';

 commit;   
 open COMMENT_CURSOR for select * from sconti.TEST;
 END; 

  END COMMENT_TEST;
```

I look forward to any response to assist me....thanks!

Comment: Please refer to this Oracle Documentation on how to create packages http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm

Comment: From first look it seems that you missing concept of `create package` and `create package body`. Check documentation in the previous comment. This is straight forward stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the link..it was very helpful...i have been scouring the net for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for certain (because you haven't shared the error you're getting), but most basic error is a lack of understanding of the specification/body.

You've put the code into the package specification, rather than the body. The specification should just have the procedure declarations (i.e. no `begin` and `end`), where as the body has the full content of the procedure.

While it won't affect compilation, there is another problem: the SQL inside the string can't access the parameters supplied to the procedure. If you must use dynamic SQL (and there's absolutely no reason to in this case), then you need a `using` clause to bind the variable into the dynamic statement. In addition, making the SQL static will allow the SQL statement to be validated at compile-time, which has obvious advantages.

A revised packaged (specification and body) is below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE comment_test IS
   PROCEDURE sp_comment (p_member_id IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_member_lastname IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_member_firstname IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_member_startdate IN DATE,
                         p_member_enddate IN DATE,
                         p_product_cat_code IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_comment IN VARCHAR2,
                         comment_cursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END comment_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY comment_test IS
   PROCEDURE sp_comment (p_member_id IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_member_lastname IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_member_firstname IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_member_startdate IN DATE,
                         p_member_enddate IN DATE,
                         p_product_cat_code IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_comment IN VARCHAR2,
                         comment_cursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO test (member_id,
                        member_lastname,
                        member_firstname,
                        member_startdate,
                        member_enddate,
                        product_cat_code,
                        comments)
      VALUES      (p_member_id,
                   p_member_lastname,
                   p_member_firstname,
                   p_member_startdate,
                   p_member_enddate,
                   p_product_cat_code,
                   p_comment);

      COMMIT;

      OPEN comment_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM sconti.test;
   END;
END comment_test;
/
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback...I have dynamic sql parameters because this procedure will be used within Cognos to provide write back capabilities..something I have done with SQL Server but not with Oracle.  The problem I am facing after editing the SPECS and BODY, is that it is erroring off on the word 'CREATE' at the beginning of the body.

Comment: Also...i wholeheartedly agree that my errors and issues were connected to the fact that I did not have a clear understanding of the package BODY and SPECS!  This thread has assisted me alot.

Comment: The complete error mentioned above is as follows:
Error(13,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Comment: I was able to compile the package, by running it as a script as opposed to compiling wihtin the package.  Thanks again!